# combine two named vectors with missing values in matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a named vector x:

```
  x <- seq(10, 80, 10)
names(x) <- month.abb[1:8]
```

...and a named vector y:

```
  y <- seq(10, 110, 10)
names(y) <- month.abb[2:12]
```

I need to combine x and y in a matrix. For missing months in either x or y, the values should be 0 (not NA). This is the matrix I need:

```
xy <- matrix(c(c(seq(10, 80, 10), 0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, seq(10, 110, 10))), nrow = 2, ncol = 12, byrow = TRUE,
             dimnames = list(c("x", "y"),
                             month.abb))
```

I'm having trouble programatically combining x and y into a matrix. Any advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `rbind.fill.matrix` from the "plyr" package:

```
library(plyr)
temp <- rbind.fill.matrix(t(x), t(y))
temp[is.na(temp)] <- 0
temp
#      Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
# [1,]  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80   0   0   0   0
# [2,]   0  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100 110
```

---

Sticking with base R, it is also possible to just use something like the following:

```
A <- matrix(0, ncol = 12)
colnames(A) <- month.abb
temp <- list(x, y)
do.call(rbind, 
        lapply(seq_along(list(x, y)), function(z) {
          A[, names(temp[[z]])] <- temp[[z]]
          A
        }))
#      Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
# [1,]  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80   0   0   0   0
# [2,]   0  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100 110
```

Comment: great thanks. I was aware of `rbind.fill`, but not `rbind.fill.matrix`

Comment: @RossAhmed, I've also added a base solution, in case you're interested.